# How to import select class in webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I tried importing select class in my program using selenium webdriver,
but I am not able to import the predefined package.

Can anyone please guide me on this?

```
package com.siri.dev;

import org.apache.bcel.generic.Select;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class MyntraTests {

    private WebDriver driver;   

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        intializedriver("firefox");
    }


    @Test
    public void get() {
        driver.get("http://www.myntra.com");
        driver=waitForPageLoaded(driver);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        System.out.println("Page opened successfully");
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("tab"));
        org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select elem = new Select(element);
        elem.selectByVisibleText("BIBA");
    }



    private void intializedriver(String browser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
```

Use

```
Select selectElement = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("")));
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are having this

> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select elem = new Select(element);

is cause you have imported a wrong class imported already

> import org.apache.bcel.generic.Select;

remove that import by deleting it and then

> import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select

If you are using Eclipse you can always remove unused imports by **ctrl+shift+o**.

Answer (score 1):

**Select** is a class of package **org.openqa.selenium.support.ui**

So you are supposed to do a import statement as follows:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
```

and then you can do your task as:

```
Select elem = new Select(element);
elem.selectByVisibleText("BIBA");
```

U have imported a wrong package : **import org.apache.bcel.generic.Select;**

Answer (score 1):

If you use Maven, you will want to know that packages under `org.openqa.selenium.support` are in artifact `selenium-support`. That does not get pulled in along with `selenium-api` or any of the `selenium-*-driver` artifacts. You can refer to the [Selenium Maven information](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp).